# Code breaks with PHP "if" statement, otherwise both functions work independently

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, conditional-statements

I have 2 functions in php which I'm using to display page content on a website.

Both of these functions work from inside the page independently and so the $_POST variables from the ajax call I have proven to myself are all present.

There are 2 pages involved plus the button, I won't bother with the button below.

**pages/pages.php** (where the problem statement is and which is called by ajax from the button)

```
  <?php

include('../config/connection.php');
$page=$_POST['page'];
$lang=$_POST['lang'];

function pageDivs($dbc, $id, $lang){
    $q="SELECT * FROM content WHERE page='$id' AND status=1";
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
    while ($data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)){ 
?>

                <div class="content" >
<?php 
                        if ($lang =='FR'){
                            echo $data['contentfr'];
                        }else{
                            echo $data['contenten'];
                        }
?>
                </div>


<?php
            }

    }

function blog($dbc,$lang){ 
?>
    <div class="bgImage homeImg"><img src="images/bgs/1566337061.jpg"></div>
    <div class="gradient"></div>
    <div class="col-md-12"> 

<?php                         
    $q = "SELECT * FROM blog  WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY id DESC";
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc,$q);
    $i=0;
    while ($data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)){ 
        $i++;
?>  

        <div id="post<?php echo $i; ?>" class="post snap">
            <div class="postBox">
                <article id="article<?php echo $i; ?>" class="article col-md-7">
                    <h3><?php echo $data['titleen'] ?></h3>
                    <?php echo $data['contenten']; ?>
                </article>
                <div id="pictureFrameLand<?php echo $i; ?>" class="pictureFrameLand col-md-4">
                    <img src="<?php 
                            $q2 = "SELECT * FROM tbl_images WHERE image_id=$data[artimage]";
                            $r2 = mysqli_query($dbc, $q2);
                            $src= mysqli_fetch_assoc($r2);
                            echo $src['urlFront']
                              ?>">
                </div>
                <div class="gradientLand col-md-4"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="spacer snap"></div>

<?php   
        } 
?>
    </div>

<?php
}
if ($page !== 'home'){
    pageDivs($dbc, $page, $lang);

} else{
    blog($dbc, $lang);
    include('../js/home.php');
}
?>
```

**js/myJS.php**(ajax calls from here, button.on(click, function(){}) )

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Create vars for Pages
  var page = 'home';
  var lang = '<?php echo $_GET['
  lang ']; ?>';
  var dataTosend = 'page=' + page + '&lang=' + lang;
  //Ajax Home Page on load
  $.ajax({
    url: "pages/pages.php",
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    data: dataTosend,
    async: true,
  }).done(function(html) {
    $("#contentCol").append(html);
    $('.content').fadeIn(1000);
  });
  //Ajax 1st 2 buttons
  $('#home').click(function() {
    page = 'home';
    lang = '<?php echo $lang; ?>';
    dataTosend = 'page=' + page + '&lang=' + lang;

    $('.active').addClass('inactive').removeClass('active');
    $('#home').removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');
    $('.content').fadeOut(500, function() {
      $('.content').remove(),
        $.ajax({
          url: "pages/pages.php",
          cache: false,
          type: 'POST',
          data: dataTosend,
          async: true,
        }).done(function(html) {
          $("#contentCol").append(html);
          $('.content').fadeIn(1000);
        });
    });
  });
  $('#bio').click(function() {
    page = 'bio';
    lang = '<?php echo $lang; ?>';
    dataTosend = 'page=' + page + '&lang=' + lang;

    $('.active').addClass('inactive').removeClass('active');
    $('#bio').removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');
    $('.content').fadeOut(500, function() {
      $('.content').remove(), $.ajax({
        url: "pages/pages.php",
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        data: dataTosend,
        async: true,
      }).done(function(html) {
        $("#contentCol").append(html);
        $('.content').fadeIn(1000);
      });
    });
  });
  //Ajax Work Dropdown
  $('#work').click(function() {
    page = 'work';
    lang = '<?php echo $lang; ?>';
    dataTosend = 'page=' + page + '&lang=' + lang;

    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $('#work').addClass('active');
    $('.content').fadeOut(500, function() {
      $('.content').remove(), $.ajax({
        url: "pages/pages.php",
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        data: dataTosend,
        async: true,
      }).done(function(html) {
        $("#contentCol").append(html);
        $('.content').fadeIn(1000);
      });
    });

  });
  $('.install').click(function() {
    page = 'install';
    lang = '<?php echo $lang; ?>';
    dataTosend = 'page=' + page + '&lang=' + lang;

    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $('#install').addClass('active');
    $('.content').fadeOut(500, function() {
      $('.content').remove(), $.ajax({
        url: "pages/pages.php",
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        data: dataTosend,
        async: true,
      }).done(function(html) {
        $("#contentCol").append(html);
        $('.content').fadeIn(1000);
      });
    });
  });
  $('.write').click(function() {
    page = 'write';
    lang = '<?php echo $lang; ?>';
    dataTosend = 'page=' + page + '&lang=' + lang;

    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $('#write').addClass('active');
    $('.content').fadeOut(500, function() {
      $('.content').remove(), $.ajax({
        url: "pages/pages.php",
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        data: dataTosend,
        async: true,
      }).done(function(html) {
        $("#contentCol").append(html);
        $('.content').fadeIn(1000);
      });
    });
  });
  $('.video').click(function() {
    page = 'video';
    lang = '<?php echo $lang; ?>';
    dataTosend = 'page=' + page + '&lang=' + lang;

    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $('#video').addClass('active');
    $('.content').fadeOut(500, function() {
      $('.content').remove(), $.ajax({
        url: "pages/pages.php",
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        data: dataTosend,
        async: true,
      }).done(function(html) {
        $("#contentCol").append(html);
        $('.content').fadeIn(1000);
      });
    });
  });
  $('.photo').click(function() {
    page = 'photo';
    lang = '<?php echo $lang; ?>';
    dataTosend = 'page=' + page + '&lang=' + lang;

    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $('#photo').addClass('active');
    $('.content').fadeOut(500, function() {
      $('.content').remove(), $.ajax({
        url: "pages/pages.php",
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        data: dataTosend,
        async: true,
      }).done(function(html) {
        $("#contentCol").append(html);
        $('.content').fadeIn(1000);
      });
    });
  });
  //Ajax Workshops dropdown
  $('#works').click(function() {
    page = 'works';
    lang = '<?php echo $lang; ?>';
    dataTosend = 'page=' + page + '&lang=' + lang;

    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $('#works').addClass('active');
    $('.content').fadeOut(500, function() {
      $('.content').remove(), $.ajax({
        url: "pages/pages.php",
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        data: dataTosend,
        async: true,
      }).done(function(html) {
        $("#contentCol").append(html);
        $('.content').fadeIn(1000);
      });
    });
  });
  $('.child').click(function() {
    page = 'child';
    lang = '<?php echo $lang; ?>';
    dataTosend = 'page=' + page + '&lang=' + lang;

    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $('#child').addClass('active');
    $('.content').fadeOut(500, function() {
      $('.content').remove(), $.ajax({
        url: "pages/pages.php",
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        data: dataTosend,
        async: true,
      }).done(function(html) {
        $("#contentCol").append(html);
        $('.content').fadeIn(1000);
      });
    });
  });
  $('.adols').click(function() {
    page = 'adols';
    lang = '<?php echo $lang; ?>';
    dataTosend = 'page=' + page + '&lang=' + lang;

    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $('#adols').addClass('active');
    $('.content').fadeOut(500, function() {
      $('.content').remove(), $.ajax({
        url: "pages/pages.php",
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        data: dataTosend,
        async: true,
      }).done(function(html) {
        $("#contentCol").append(html);
        $('.content').fadeIn(1000);
      });
    });
  });
  $('.adult').click(function() {
    page = 'adult';
    lang = '<?php echo $lang; ?>';
    dataTosend = 'page=' + page + '&lang=' + lang;

    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $('#adult').addClass('active');
    $('.content').fadeOut(500, function() {
      $('.content').remove(), $.ajax({
        url: "pages/pages.php",
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        data: dataTosend,
        async: true,
      }).done(function(html) {
        $("#contentCol").append(html);
        $('.content').fadeIn(1000);
      });
    });
  });
  //Ajax Last button    
  $('#contact').click(function() {
    page = 'contact';
    lang = '<?php echo $lang; ?>';
    dataTosend = 'page=' + page + '&lang=' + lang;

    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $('#contact').addClass('active');
    $('.content').fadeOut(500, function() {
      $('.content').remove(), $.ajax({
        url: "pages/pages.php",
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        data: dataTosend,
        async: true,
      }).done(function(html) {
        $("#contentCol").append(html);
        $('.content').fadeIn(1000);
      });
    });
  });

  //Collapse Dropdowns with other buttons
  $('.bbutt').click(function() {
    $('#collapseOne1').removeClass('show');
    $('#collapseTwo1').removeClass('show');
  });
  $('#work').click(function() {
    $('#collapseTwo1').removeClass('show');
  });

  $('#works').click(function() {
    $('#collapseOne1').removeClass('show');
  });

  //debug
  $('#console-debug').hide();
  $('#btn-debug').on("click", function() {
    $('#console-debug').toggle();
  });

  //    Hide NavBar after 5s and show on rollover

  //$('#navCol').hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
  //$('#navCol').show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);




});
</script>
```

I know there's a lot of code there and you only really need 2 of the button ajax calls to see the method but it's worth pointing out that there are that many potential calls from buttons; so I included the whole file.

**The Culprit Statement** is at the end of pages.php:

```
 <?php
}
if ($page !== 'home'){
    pageDivs($dbc, $page, $lang);

} else{
    blog($dbc, $lang);
    include('../js/home.php');
}
?>
```

Now, what's strange is that only home works like this, so !=='home' is skipped and blog runs, proving that both $dbc and $lang are available. no button changes from this page.

But if I do this:

```
    pageDivs($dbc, $page, $lang);
/*
if ($page !== 'home'){

} else{
    blog($dbc, $lang);
    include('../js/home.php');
}
*/
```

Then pageDivs() runs, proving that infact $page is set and available...

### Edit

I should also point out that I started the If statement as just != and then later moved to !== and had no effect.

Edit2:

For Rasclatt, here is the button html output. I had to keep the href or my css breaks, but I can remove it and rewrite my css if it's gonna need to be buttons:

```
<div id="navCol" class="col-sm-1">
    <!--nav in here-->

    <ul id="mainNav" class="nav navbar">
        <!--beginning of main list-->

        <li class="nav navbar navbar-text">
            <a id="home" href="#home" data-acton="#home" data-page="home" class="bbutt do-action active"> Home </a>
        </li>


        <li class="nav navbar navbar-text">
            <a id="bio" href="#bio" data-acton="#bio" data-page="bio" class="bbutt do-action inactive"> Biography </a>
        </li>


        <li>
            <div id="accordion1" class="accordion" role="tablist">
                <div id="header-card" class="card accordion">
                    <div class="card-header accordion accordion-header work" role="tab" id="headingOne1">
                        <h5 class="mb-0"> <a id="work" class="do-action" data-page="work" data-toggle="collapse" data-acton="#work" href="#collapseOne1" role="button" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne1"> Work </a> </h5>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseOne1" class="collapse accordion" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne1" data-parent="#accordion1">

                        <div class='card-body accordion accordion-item inactive'>
                            <a id="install" data-page="install" class="do-action install" href="#install" data-acton="#install" class="subs first">
                    Installations 
                </a>

                        </div>
                        <div class='card-body accordion accordion-item inactive'>
                            <a id="write" data-page="write" class="do-action write" href="#write" data-acton="#write" class="subs">
                    Writing 
                </a>

                        </div>
                        <div class='card-body accordion accordion-item inactive'>
                            <a id="video" data-page="video" class="do-action video" href="#video" data-acton="#video" class="subs">
                    Video 
                </a>

                        </div>
                        <div class='card-body accordion accordion-item inactive'>
                            <a id="photo" data-page="photo" class="do-action photo" href="#photo" data-acton="#photo" class="subs last">
                    Photography 
                </a>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li>
            <div id="accordion2" class="accordion" role="tablist">
                <div id="header-card" class="card accordion">
                    <div class="card-header accordion accordion-header2 works" role="tab" id="headingTwo1">
                        <h6 class="mb-0"> <a id="works" class="do-action" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo1" data-acton="#workshops" data-page="works" role="button" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo1">Workshops</a> </h6>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseTwo1" class="collapse accordion" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo1" data-parent="#accordion2">

                        <div class='card-body accordion accordion-item inactive'>
                            <a id="child" data-page="child" class="do-action child" href="#child" data-acton="#child" class="subs first">
                    Children 
                </a>

                        </div>
                        <div class='card-body accordion accordion-item inactive'>
                            <a id="adols" data-page="adols" class="do-action adols" href="#adols" data-acton="#adols" class="subs">
                    Adolescents 
                </a>

                        </div>
                        <div class='card-body accordion accordion-item inactive'>
                            <a id="adult" data-page="adult" class="do-action adult" href="#adult" data-acton="#adult" class="subs last">
                    Adults 
                </a>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li class="nav navbar navbar-text">
            <a id="contact" href="#contact" data-acton="#contact" data-page="contact" class="bbutt do-action inactive"> Contact </a>
        </li>


    </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging to check the value of `$page` and it's type?

Comment: your html\php mix, especially in the functions is really hard to fathom.

Comment: with code hinting in DW it's much clearer hence why i do it this way.

Comment: @john3136 It doesn't want to change the value from home if I print $page but only when the if statement is employed, without it changes correctly

Comment: PHP works. `if ($left !== $right)` works. In your case right is a literal string so all that is left is `$left` is not what you think it is. It is either not a string, or it doesn't equal 'home' - perhaps it has whitespace tacked on the end? In fact looks like your literal has a space on the end - are you sure `$page` has a training space too?

Comment: It's good practice to test `POST` and `GET` variables before assigning them to other variables. e.g. `if(isset($_POST['page'])){...}else{...}`

Comment: still makes no difference though does it, even though I am sure that it is set it doesn't run anything but blog(). simply having no check for it outside of the function has the effect of losing it.

Comment: Put `var_dump($page);` before the `if` statement, what does it show?

Comment: simply not checking for it outside the function makes it work is what I meant

Comment: @Barmar homestring(4)

Comment: never changes with button presses

Comment: when it works i get biostring(3) "bio", so on homestring(4) also has "home", that's when I take the statement out.

Comment: i think it's in the buttons somewhere maybe now.... the jquery ajax... like a not closed function or bracket...

Comment: `homestring(4)` not `string(4) "home"`?

Comment: It's best to examine it in the AJAX response in the Network tab of the browser console, rather than what's rendered in the browser window.

Comment: so I get GET and POST outside the conditional, but back inside and I get neither. I do get the initial POST for home page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you load the page for the first time it goes on home which is fine, but when you click on other button (bio,work,etc.) it fetch the content of both because every time you include the js/home.php it executes the ajax function below along with the `$('#other').click` . due to which you end up making 2 ajax call

```
 //Ajax Home Page on load
  $.ajax({
    url: "pages/pages.php",
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    data: dataTosend,
    async: true,
  }).done(function(html) {
    $("#contentCol").append(html);
    $('.content').fadeIn(1000);
  });
```

before including the page i suggest you to add extra flag variable just to skip ajax call to home

```
}
if ($page !== 'home'){
    pageDivs($dbc, $page, $lang);

} else{
    blog($dbc, $lang);
    $donotloadhome = true;
    include('../js/home.php');
}
```

and in the script add a varible too.

```
var skipflag = '<?php echo ($donotloadhome)?'call':''; ?>';
if(skipflag != 'call')
{
  //Ajax Home Page on load
  $.ajax({
    url: "pages/pages.php",
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    data: dataTosend,
    async: true,
  }).done(function(html) {
    $("#contentCol").append(html);
    $('.content').fadeIn(1000);
  });
}
```

Comment: makes some sense. 1st I'm going to condense it like Raclatt has said but I'll probably try to implement this too. seems only reasonable to chack for as many things as possible in the code to eliminate potetial for errors likethis 1. thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

Couple things here; you have a PHP syntax anomaly in your javascript on this line:

```
var lang = '<?php echo $_GET['
lang ']; ?>';
```

try bringing it up on one line and remove spaces in the key name:

```
var lang = '<?php echo $_GET['lang']; ?>';
```

Secondly, you should not be repeating your JavaScript sections over and over. You can reduce it to one ajax function and then use other DOM elements to indicate your intentions to that function, for example:

```
<script>
// Wrap your stuff in one function and inject what you need that changes
function doAjaxCall(btn, page, lang)
{
    // Set the query string
    var dataTosend = 'page=' + page + '&lang=' + lang;
    // If is obj do the button stuff
    if(btn !== false) {
        $('.active').addClass('inactive').removeClass('active');
        btn.removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');
    }
    // Run the ajax and all that jazz
    $('.content').fadeOut(500, function() {
        $('.content').remove();
        $.ajax({
          url: "pages/pages.php",
          cache: false,
          type: 'POST',
          data: dataTosend,
          async: true,
        }).done(function(html) {
          $("#contentCol").append(html);
          $('.content').fadeIn(1000);
        });
    });
}
// Set document ready
$(function(){
    // Just send the language once, make sure to try and remove any possible
    // user hackery...
    var lang = '<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET["lang"], ENT_QUOTES) ?>';
    // Run the default ajax on page load
    doAjaxCall(false, 'home', lang);
    // Just listen for one element on click now
    $(this).on('click', '.do-action', function(){
        // If the element that is being clicked is the same one that is going
        // to have the .active done to it, then just use $(this) only
        doAjaxCall($($(this).data('acton')), $(this).data('page'), lang);
    });
});

//Collapse Dropdowns with other buttons
$('.bbutt').click(function() {
    $('#collapseOne1').removeClass('show');
    $('#collapseTwo1').removeClass('show');
});
$('#work').click(function() {
    $('#collapseTwo1').removeClass('show');
});

$('#works').click(function() {
    $('#collapseOne1').removeClass('show');
});

//debug
$('#console-debug').hide();
$('#btn-debug').on("click", function() {
    $('#console-debug').toggle();
});
</script>
```

The trigger html would be something like this:

```
<!-- Add the "do-action" class to everything that you want to fire the ajax -->
<!-- Then you can put the page destination in the data attribute -->
<!-- Using $(this) probably would work in the js but, use the acton data attribute to send the intended object to act on -->
<button id="home" class="do-action" data-acton="#home" data-page="home">Home<button>

<button id="install" class="do-action" data-acton="#install" data-page="install">Install<button>
```

Anyway, by making only one function, you reduce the chances you will make a copy/paste error and will clean up your JS greatly.

Finally, since you are mixing all kinds of html/functions/business/view login together, you may want to wrap your PHP functions with a check for exists:

```
if(!function_exists('pageDivs')) {
    function pageDivs($dbc, $id, $lang)
    {
        $r = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM content WHERE page='$id' AND status = 1");
        while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)): ?>

        <div class="content" >
            <?php echo ($lang =='FR')? $data['contentfr'] : $data['contenten'] ?>
        </div>

        <?php endwhile;
    }
}

if(!function_exists('blog')) {
    function blog($dbc, $lang)
    { ?>

        <div class="bgImage homeImg">
            <img src="images/bgs/1566337061.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="gradient"></div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <?php                         
            $r = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM blog  WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY id DESC");
            $i=0;
            while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)):
                $i++; ?>  
            <div id="post<?php echo $i; ?>" class="post snap">
                <div class="postBox">
                    <article id="article<?php echo $i; ?>" class="article col-md-7">
                        <h3><?php echo $data['titleen'] ?></h3>
                        <?php echo $data['contenten']; ?>
                    </article>
                    <div id="pictureFrameLand<?php echo $i; ?>" class="pictureFrameLand col-md-4">
                        <img src="<?php
                        $q2 = "SELECT * FROM tbl_images WHERE image_id = ".$data['artimage'];
                        $r2 = mysqli_query($dbc, $q2);
                        $src= mysqli_fetch_assoc($r2);
                        echo $src['urlFront']
                        ?>" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="gradientLand col-md-4"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="spacer snap"></div>

            <?php endwhile ?>
        </div>

    <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198406/discussion-on-answer-by-rasclatt-code-breaks-with-php-if-statement-otherwise).